# Unexpected text 'var _spUserId=1' in welcome control on custom Master Page

Tags: master-page, browser-compatibility

I have a custom Master Page. But I when I view it in FireFox I have some additional text after the Welcome Control. It's not there in Internet Explorer.

The Text is:

Welcome,.... **var _spUserId=1** Websiteactions

The bold writing is the thing thats incorrect. I think it's something with the welcome-control because I made some marks around it.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was a css-tag.

#pageHeadTop *
{
   display: inline; 
}

Answer (score 0):

var _spUserId=1 is the javascript that stores the ID of the current user in the UserInfo list.

Could you have removed a `<script>` tag when customizing the master page?